# How to 'git commit' a single file/directory

Tags: git, git-commit

I tried the following command:

```
git commit path/to/my/file.ext -m 'my notes'
```

And received an error in Git version 1.5.2.1:

```
error: pathspec '-m' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'MY MESSAGE' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Is that incorrect syntax for a single file or directory commits?

Comment: Are you sure you have your version correct? Updating _to_ 1.5.2.1? 1.5.2.1 is over 4 years old now.

Comment: Is anything prohibiting you from upgrading git?

Comment: BTW: This was a VM spun up from an old recipe. Local Git was up to date, didn't realize this version was ancient. Strictness changed.

Answer (score 425, accepted):

Your arguments are in the wrong order. Try `git commit -m 'my notes' path/to/my/file.ext`, or if you want to be more explicit, `git commit -m 'my notes' -- path/to/my/file.ext`.

Incidentally, Git v1.5.2.1 is 4.5 years old. You may want to update to a newer version (1.7.8.3 is the current release).

Comment: You make a good observation.  However, interestingly Git 1.7.5.1 on Windows blithely accepts `git commit path_to_file -m 'message'`

Comment: @SriSankaran: Sounds like they taught it to recognize out-of-order arguments then. But according to the documentation, the correct order is to put the file list last, and it's probably a good idea to stick to the documented version of things.

Comment: Thanks. The order of these messages changed... or at least the strictness of the order changed ;)

Comment: BTW: This was a sandbox machine spun up from an old VM recipe. My local Git was up to date, but didn't realize this version was old (bad assumption and not knowing the version number history). Thanks all.

Comment: I vote down for one reason: it won't work in GIT Bash when I'm trying to commit the whole Unity project.

Comment: @DavidDimalanta: What do you mean?

Comment: I'm trying to commit a whole Unity project using your solution as provided. Before that, I have to git add the whole project folder except the filename "UnityLockfile" at Temp folder. I ignore it. Next, I decided to commit it although it will commit all the added new files only before ready to push it. It is worked on other project folders but except for Unity.

Comment: @KevinBallard I see my errors though. Active files may cannot be committed nor pushed until do so. And, I decided do this format for entering directory like this: git commit "C:/path/to/my/file" -m "Committed a directory"

Comment: On Windows with the Git CMD console I had to use `"Double Quotes"`.

Comment: what are the meaning/benefits of the -- in the 'more explicit solution' ?

Comment: @ihebiheb Looking right now I don't see any other non-flag parameters to `git commit` so I guess the answer is "nothing", but in many other git commands the `--` distinguishes paths from other freeform arguments (for example, with `git log` the `--` prevents a path from being interpreted as a revision range instead)

Answer (score 112):

Try:

```
git commit -m 'my notes' path/to/my/file.ext
```

of if you are in the current directory, add `./` to the front of the path;

```
git commit -m 'my notes' ./path/to/my/file.ext
```

Comment: For me, it doesn't work without double quotes ", use `git commit -m "my notes" ./name_of_file.ext`

Answer (score 20):

If you are in the folder which contains the file

```
git commit -m 'my notes' ./name_of_file.ext
```

Comment: if I am already in the file, do I need a leading "./" (dot forward-slash)?  could I use `git commit -m "my note" name_of_file.txt`?

Comment: @Chris22 I am not sure what you mean by "if I am already in the file" (maybe you meant "in the directory"?)... `./` is just normal path syntax, but yes, not necessary in this example.

Answer (score 11):

Use the `-o` option.

```
git commit -o path/to/myfile -m "the message"
```

> -o, --only            commit only specified files

Comment: That option isn't necessary. If you include a file page in your commit command it will only commit those files.

Comment: Good to know if you want to make sure when messing with further params, e.g. `--amend`

Answer (score 8):

Specify the path after the entered commit message, like:

```
git commit -m "commit message" path/to/file.extension
```

Answer (score 5):

For Git 1.9.5 on Windows 7: "my Notes" (double quotes) corrected this issue. In my case, putting the file(s) before or after the -m 'message' made no difference; using single quotes was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you are working on big project and have opened multiple files, and you made changes in single file, when you don't need to write `git add .`, this will add all the files to git, so you first need to check where you made changes by `git status`, here you will see all the paths next to the filenames, copy the path of the file where you made change and then write `git add path`, here path is whole line of path to the file (your modified file). Then you write your commit message by `git -m "message"` and then push.

This will push only the specified file which you have used with `git add file`

Answer (score -5):

You try if you are in the master branch:

```
git commit -m "Commit message" -- filename.ext
```