# How to write single commit message for each package in Android?

Tags: android, git, github, intellij-idea, git-commit

I always struggle to write commit messages for each `package` in android,when i upload the **project** to the **GitHub**,i want to have good different commit message for each package in my repository.

Is there any suggestions please?

Here is my Screenshot:

[image: As you see the packages,how can i write different commit message?]

Answer (score 1):

**The commit message is hard linked with a commit**.

**It is not possible to have multiple commit message in the same commit.**

If you want different commit message for every package you need to do a commit for every single package.

Comment: I had seen a lot of android projects in **Github** which has different messages in each **package** or **file**.how can i make commit for every single package?

Comment: this is another simple question: [How to git commit a single file/directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795097/how-to-git-commit-a-single-file-directory)

Comment: please vote up and accept the response if you think is usefull